# What should I say for a comic relief?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Person A: what would she be later on in life?

**Person B: I'll tell you what she would be — she would be the mother of my children.**

Or

**Person B: I'll tell you what she would be — she will be the mother of my children.**

Comment: "Would" doesn't really work here. Better to say: "What will she be later in life?" (or better, "What will she be when she grows up?"). "I'll tell what she'll be: [she'll be] the mother of my children." (Or better, keep B's answer simpler and snappier: "The mother of my children."

Comment: I'm using "Would" as a speculative mood here.

Comment: I can't think of a realistic context for using "would", unless it's a discussion reflecting on past events. But then neither of the B responses listed would fit with that. ("What would she go on to be? Turns out, she became the mother of my kids …"